# Display application logs on jenkins console log

Tags: java, jenkins

Overview of task: I have a java application which runs for multiple clients (i run the application from command line using java). This application creates logs in a file inside `/tmp/client_name.logs` for each client.

I want to create Jenkins job with a number of stages, one stage per client, where i want to display each client's log in respective stage logs. My question is how can i display the `/tmp/client_name.logs` file contents on Jenkins.

For now Jenkins only display the console output logs.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a pipeline using the [`sh` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) (I'd use `readFile` and then `echo`, but I believe it only works on files within the workspace) to run the clients and then output the log contents in the console output, e.g.:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Client A') {
      sh './run-client-a'
      sh 'cat /tmp/client_a.logs'
    }
    stage('Client B') {
      sh './run-client-b'
      sh 'cat /tmp/client_b.logs'
  }
}
```